# How can I make a RequiredFieldValidator trigger a message elsewhere on the page?

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, validation

I have a page with a repeater containing RadioButtonLists which have requiredFieldValidators attached to them. I need to keep the RFV next to the control (it's the only way I can get it to work to be honest!)

However, the form is made up of a few sections contained in an accordion. This means that when the form is submitted, the item that has failed validation may not be visible, so the user won't know where the error is.

Is there a way I can also have a message by the submit button which is triggered by an RFV changing saying "please go back and check your answers" or something? I guess I'd need to use JQuery / JavaScript as it would be clientside.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a special [ValidationSummary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.validationsummary%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) control for that:

```
<asp:ValidationSummary ID="Summary" runat="server"
    DisplayMode="SingleParagraph"
    HeaderText="Please go back and check your answers" />
```

This control is used to summarize all validation errors on the page.

Answer (score 2):

Try "ValidationSummary". look for example from here.

```
http://www.w3schools.com/aspnet/control_validationsummary.asp
```

Comment: Just pipped to the post by Andrei ;-) - Thanks very much for answering though - it worked a treat.